# Why do I always get extra one day with date difference in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to calculate the seconds between a date from now, however, I always get extra one day when adding the seconds from now.

```
echo $(($(date -ud "2020-03-15 19:13" +'%s') - $(date +'%s')))
```

As of posting, the result is `1744204`

Using this [website](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=24&m1=2&y1=2020&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=&h1=22&i1=43&s1=5&ah=&ai=&as=1744204&rec=) to check, I gets 16 March, not 15 March as expected. Any idea why?

Comment: `gdate -ud "$(($(gdate -ud "2020-03-15 19:13" +'%s') - $(gdate +'%s'))) seconds" -> 
Sun Mar 15 19:13:00 UTC 2020` Is this different from what you get? Perhaps the website is in a confusing timezone?

Comment: AFAIK you should not call `date` with the `-u` option and other options at the same time. It is either `date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]` or  `date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]` but not both.

Comment: `date -ud@"$(($(date -ud '2020-2-24 22:43:5' +%s) + 1744204))"` outputs 16 March for me. @vdavid I think I could point out, that `-u` could be one of `OPTION`s, so maybe it's valid.

Comment: Are you forgetting about Feb 29 this year?

Comment: @kojiro that did converts it to corrects date and time, but the raw result is still incorrect. Using the same command, change it to few seconds from now, it returns 28XXX which is definitely wrong.

Comment: `u` is one of the options.

Comment: @chepner I don't think that's relevant..

Comment: It doesn't add an extra day. 1744204 is 20 days and __4 hours__. So `'2020-2-24 22:43:5' + 1744204 ` will be 16 march, but `'2020-2-24 14:42:56' + 1744204` is 15 march. Note `$(($(date -ud"2020-03-15 19:13" +'%s') - $(date -ud '2020-2-24 14:42:56' +%s) )) = 1744204`

Comment: I think it's very relevant: `date -d "2019-02-24 + 1744204 seconds"` returns Mar 16; `date -d "2020-02-24 + 1744204 seconds"` returns Mar 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

verify the result of your date commands and verify the timezone of both.

The first result of the command shows the timestamp in UTC, and the second one shows the timestamp using the timezone of the system.

Here is the difference:

```
$ date -ud "2020-03-15 19:13" +'%s'
1584299580
```

With UTC-3 in my system:

```
$ date -d "2020-03-15 19:13" +'%s'
1584310380
```

I hope that help you.

Comment: You're absolutely right, seems like that's the issue here. Modified to `echo $(($(date -d "2020-03-15 19:13" +'%s') - $(date -d now +'%s')))` and now it's all correct, thank you.